# How to make my navigation-bar invisible on mobile version of web site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I am making a website and I have a problem. My navigation bar is showing up on a mobile version of the site while it is off and that should not happen. I tried to find the solution online but I can't find anything. If you know a solution please help me. Here is the code if someone wants to help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Exemple</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
        <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="kocka">
            <div class="linija1"></div>
            <div class="linija2"></div>
            <div class="linija3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header>

    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
<script rel="stylesheet" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(48, 47, 47, 0.816);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    min-height: 8vh;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 60%;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: large;
}

.nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
}
.kocka{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.kocka div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: rgba(48, 47, 47, 0.816);
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;

    }
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .kocka{
        display: block;
    }
}

    .nav-active {
        transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinksFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .linija1{
    transform:rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px , 6px); 
} 
.toggle .linija2{
    opacity: 0;
} 
.toggle .linija3{
    transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-5px , -6px);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const kocka = document.querySelector('.kocka');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navlinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    kocka.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        navlinks.forEach((link , index)=>{
            if(link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation = 'none'
            }else{ 
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7+1.5}s`;   
            }
        });
        kocka.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });
    
}

navSlide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)  to change your css according to the size of the screen:

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(48, 47, 47, 0.816);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    min-height: 8vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   nav {
     display:none;
   }
}
```

This will make your nav invisible in screens smaller than 480px wide.

Comment: Hello João Pedro, your reply is useful to me. I have just one more question to ask. How wide do I need to set my max width for an average phone screen?

Comment: I think 480px it's good as it will get most of the devices. You can go to Chrome, press F12 and click on the mobile phone with tablet icon (if you can't find it just press Ctrl+Shift+M) and it will change to mobile mode and you can choose from a list of devices, the iPhone 12 has 390px of width, Galaxy S22 has 412px, you can check till what size you want to keep this layout